# Does complex analysis generalize to analysis of $2\times2$ invertible matrices?

Tags: complex-analysis, matrix-analysis

We can encode the complex numbers as matrices by letting $1$ be the identity matrix and $i = \left( \begin{array}{clcr} 0 & -1\\1 & 0 \end{array} \right)$. From this fact, this means that complex analysis is equivalent to the analysis of matrices of the form $ \left( \begin{array}{clcr} a & -b\\b & a \end{array} \right)$.

If we removed the restriction on the form of the matrices, and instead studied all invertible $2\times2$ matrices, how much of the theorems from complex analysis would generalize to this new system? Is there any place where I could read more about this?

Comment: Not much, I think, because invertible $2\times 2$ matrices do not form a field.

Comment: Note that the set of invertible $2\times 2$ matrices is not even closed under addition.

Comment: If you use general $2\times2$ (real) matrices, you just get (two-dimensional) multivariable calculus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of real matrices of the form $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a & -b \\ b & a\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ together with matrix addition and matrix multiplication form a [*field*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)), that is, the field of complex numbers.

The set of all real $2\times 2$ matrices with the same addition and multiplication forms a unitary ring that is not commutative, does not admit inverses for all non-zero elements and hence misses a lot of properties that a field has.

Now the analysis for complex functions and such gadgets heavily depends on $\mathbb C$ being a field, so most of it will fail for functions over the ring of all real $2\times 2$ matrices.